# PHP curl upload seems to send only 10 bytes?

Tags: php, curl, upload

It seems that curl uploads only 10 bytes.
The $url is correct, and $file path is also correct and the file exists!

I have this code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    $post   = array(
        "id" => $id,
        "api_key" => $api_key,
        "file" => "@".$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/".$file
        );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: How do you know it is only uploading 10 bytes?  Are you monitoring the outgoing packets to see what is actually being sent over HTTP?  What does var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch)); show?

Answer (score 0):

If the url is correct the code looks fine to me. Have you checked the $file_path is valid and have read permission?